# How to set enum to public in namespace C++

Tags: c#, c++, enums, namespaces, public

How do you set enum in a namespace to public so that it can be accessed anywhere in the code?
I am trying to convert a C# program to c++

I put

```
namespace foo {
public: enum foo{}
}
```

but that clearly doesn't work.
any suggestions?

Comment: It's already public. And for a more accurate conversion, you'll want `enum class`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, anything in a namespace is public. Just use:

```
namespace foo {
    enum foo {
        bar,
        baz
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is already public as it is defined in a namespace.May be you can try like this:-

```
namespace foo
    {
        class ABC
        {
            public:
                enum foo
                {
                    GOOD,
                    BAD
                };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Access specifiers (`public`, `protected`, and `private`) **only** apply to class members and inheritance. Namespaces have nothing to do with them.